# Пояснение к алгоритмической задаче. Перестановки целых чисел

Tags: алгоритм, комбинаторика

Здравствуйте!

Имеется такая задача:

> "Перестановки". Напишите алгоритм
> нахождения всех перестановок целых
> чисел от 1 до N. Указание: Множество
> перестановок целых чисел от 1 до N
> можно получить из множества
> перестановок целых чисел от 1 до N −
> 1, вставляя N во все возможные позиции
> в каждой перестановке длины N − 1.

Как реализовать данную задачу рекурсивно, я представляю и смогу сделать, в этом нет проблемы.

Суть в том, что я не совсем пойму с временной сложностью этой программы.

Можно так задать вопрос:

> Является ли задача NP-полной, или
> P-задачей, или иной. И почему?
>
> И при каких значениях N данная задача
> реально решаемая за разумное время на
> домашнем ПК?

Собственно, проблема у меня с оценкой этой задачи.
Разъясните, пожалуйста, кто знает.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно определению, классификация проблем [**P**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_%28complexity%29)/[**NP**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_%28complexity%29) относится к задачам, имеющим ответом [«да» или «нет»](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem). Поскольку ваша задача таковой не является, она не относится ни к одному из этих классов.

*Ваш К. О.*

**Обновление**

С временной сложностью, поскольку нужно вывести `n!` перестановок, то в лучшем случае `O(n!) = O(sqrt(n) (n/e)^n) = O(sqrt(n) exp(n ln n - n))`. То есть даже больше, чем экспонента. Так что всё довольно кисло.

Насколько мне помнится, вычисление каждой следующей перестановки можно свести к `O(1)` или в крайнем случае `O(log n)`, так что реальный ответ будет не сильно отличаться от оценки.

**Обновление 2**

[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp): Будем отталкиваться от 1 Г/с. Для записи перестановки размером `n` нужно по идее `n log_2 n` бит. Поскольку всех перестановок около `sqrt(n * 2 * pi) (n/e)^n`, суммарное количество байт около `sqrt(2 * pi)/8 * n^1.5 * log_2 n * (n/e)^n`, время `sqrt(2 * pi)/8 * n^1.5 * log_2 n * (n/e)^n / 2^30` сек.

Вот что получается: http://pastebin.com/sgRVsBAm

При `n >= 10` уже нереалистично.

**Обновление 3**

И правда, ошибся, кодируя формулу Стирлинга. Надо делить на `e`, а я умножил.

Скорректированный результат: http://pastebin.com/AdVCmHBJ

Comment: А причем тут это? Есть класс P-задач, есть класс NP-задач. Решение о равенстве этих классов даст лишь возможность или невозможность решать NP-задачи за полиномиальное время, а не изменить список этих задач.

Comment: О как, действительно очевидно, как-то не задумывался об этом. Спасибо!
А можете пояснить: что с временной сложностью данной задачи?
Или тут нужно смотреть после реализации.

Comment: @Daniil  Manin: Обновил ответ

Comment: Причем на практике это время похоже будет определяться скоростью вывода результатов на носитель.

Comment: Спасибо! Вы мне очень помогли!

Comment: @avp: Точно! Отсюда можно и оценку времени сделать. Какие у нас теперь средние скорости винтов? :)

Comment: @Daniil  Manin: Пожалуйста!

Comment: Ну, на пустом (со свежей файловой системой) можно приблизиться к 100Mbytes/sec.

Если же взять хороший дисковый массив и "страйпнуть" логический том, то на приличном сервере через параллельные Fibre Chanal наверное можно и гиг/сек показать.

Comment: @avp: Обновил ответ

Comment: на практике же, у меня:
при n=9, алгоритм прорабатывает за 4-5 секунд, с выводом всех перестановок.
при n=10, алгоритм прорабатывает за 38-40 секунд, с выводом всех перестановок.
при n=12, алгоритм прорабатывает за 1 минуту 40 секунд, без вывода.